# How could I insert a formula in a Word document header?

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I'm trying to add a formula/expression in my Word document programatically. In my scenario I need to get the number of pages minus 1. If you try to do it in the document itself it should look like this:

```
{={NUMPAGES \*MERGEFORMAT }-1}
```

Now that I'm trying to do it via code I'm struggling... I've tried to do this:

```
RangeWord.Fields.Add(this.Range, Interop.WdFieldType.wdFieldExpression, "{NUMPAGES \*MERGEFORMAT }-1", true)
```

But in that case `{NUMPAGES \*MERGEFORMAT}` doesn't work as a field but as a plain text. How could I achieve what I want ? Should I add a new field for `{NUMPAGES \*MERGEFORMAT}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it will work this way. Entering braces into code does not work in any way.
This, however, should do the trick just fine:

```
doc.Variables.Add("myNumPages", doc.ComputeStatistics(Interop.WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages) - 1);
RangeWord.Fields.Add(this.Range, Interop.WdFieldType.wdFieldDocVariable, "myNumPages");
```

.

**Edit/AddIt:** There is another way, with the advantage of then having a dynamic field that can be updated:

1. Insert a normal `{NUMPAGES}` field somewhere and give it a white font or make it hidden
2. Select the field, add a bookmark "numpages" covering this entire field
3. Now add a *Formula* field with the formula `=numpages-1`

Example:

```
var hidField = RangeWord.Fields.Add(this.Range, Interop.WdFieldType.wdFieldExpression, "NUMPAGES");
hidField.Result.Bookmarks.Add("numpages");
hidField.Result.Font.Hidden = 1;
RangeWord.Fields.Add(this.Range, Interop.WdFieldType.wdFieldFormula, "numpages-1");
```

You might have to play around with the range variable so as to not overwrite your hidden field.

Comment: I know the next question may seem offtopic but it's something I need to know... Are `Variables` references ? I mean if I decide to change my "myNumPages" variable (if it could be done), will it update all the fields which contain that variable?

Comment: You would have to recalculate the variable. I have just tried adding a few pages and then updating the field - no change. i.e. you must reassign the value to the variable, since it is static.

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez I have amended the code. The second version should be the way to go for you.